# Postifix: use myorigin=$myhostname for local email and myorigin=$mydomain for trusted networks

Tags: postfix

I have a postfix instance configured for address rewriting which allow canonicalization of from header.

### Current (required?) configurations

This are the relevant configurations:

```
# Basic conf
myhostname = hostname.example.test
mydomain = example.test
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8,1.2.3.4/32
myorigin = $mydomain
mydestination =

# Rewrite options
append_at_myorigin = yes
local_header_rewrite_clients = permit_mynetworks
sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient, header_recipient
recipient_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical

# restrictions (redacted for readability)
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_sender, permit
```

### Desired result

I want to achieve that:

1. when an email is received from 127.0.0.1, `From: root` is rewritten as `From: root@hostname.example.test` (i.e. root@$hostname)
2. when an email is received from 1.2.3.4, `From: root` is rewritten as `From: root@example.test` (i.e. root@$mydomain)
3. when an email is received from anyone else, an email `From: root` is rejected (since restriction `reject_non_fqdn_sender` is in place)

### The problem

The variable `$myorigin` should be different based on the receiving address, but I cannot find a way to do so. So, far I've tried many solutions but failed.

### Unsuccessful attempt...

I've tried creating two smtp master services -- `127.0.0.1:smtp` with `myorigin = $myhostname` and `192.168.1.2:smtp` with `myorigin = $mydomain` -- but since the myorigin option is related to process trivial-rewrites it gets ignored.

Mapping for `canonical`/`virtual` seems to be unusable since they happens after trivial rewrites is executed.

Mapping for `aliases` seems to be unusable since they are used after the message is determined to be sent to `$mydestination`, but this messages elsewhere.

Comment: *"it gets ignored"* I could not say without trying whether that helps, but you *can* duplicate `trivial-rewrite` instances (e.g. with different `-o remote_header_rewrite_domain=example.invalid` settings) and point `smtpd` instances in `master.cf` to alternates via `-o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject -o rewrite_service_name=rewrite-local`.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree that the sender should fix their servers. Problem is that I it should be configurable, and the client should be able to receive from very old systems (e.g. AS400).

Comment: Great hint with `rewrite_service_name`! Didn't noticed that I can replace every process using `*_service_name` I'm figuring out how to solve this scenario and then will publish the answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have seen problems that could be solved that way, and some where that did not help (if you wanted post-queue changes, you could as well run two instances), I only know it works reliably for replacing `cleanup`. Since simpler maintenance and diagnostics is still preferable, could you not deal with the "configurable" requirement by canonicalizing *all* locally administered names of some agreed suffix, yet still requiring that the senders follow spec insofar as sending proper names, even if not the ones eventually used?

Comment: I see what you are suggesting and generally agreed that canonicalization is a good thing. Since this software is used by other mail administrator, on the behalf of the user, you probably see why I just want for locally generated "root"/"postmaster" email, to be rewritten with the hostname; I'll handle SPF validation on the hostname level and no one but the system can generate such email. This time I live with this master.cf configuration, maybe a postmulti will be required next time.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [anx](https://serverfault.com/questions/1116258/postifix-use-myorigin-myhostname-for-local-email-and-myorigin-mydomain-for-tr#comment1457871_1116258) feedback I found the solution.

### The solution scheme

According to [Postfix official docs](https://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#overview) about rewriting, the master process tree is like the following:

```
smtp   --+--> cleanup --> rewrite --> [queue]
pickup --/
```

So I ended up creating a pipeline specific for localhost, like the following:

```
192.168.1.2:smtp  --+--> cleanup --> rewrite ------------+--> [queue]
127.0.0.1:smtp  --+--> cleanup_local --> rewrite_local --/
pickup -----------/
```

### The configuration

This is the `main.cf` configuration, which represent external IP configurations:

```ini
#  configure the global desiderata

# Basic conf (for display purpose, use your own configuration)
# myhostname = hostname.example.test
# mydomain = example.test
# mydestination =
# mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8,1.2.3.4/32

# Rewrite options
myorigin = $mydomain
append_at_myorigin = yes
local_header_rewrite_clients = permit_mynetworks
sender_canonical_classes = envelope_sender, header_sender
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_canonical
recipient_canonical_classes = envelope_recipient, header_recipient
recipient_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_canonical

# restrictions (redacted for readability)
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_non_fqdn_sender, permit
```

This is the `master.cf` configuration, with the customized pipeline:

```ini
# add this for local smtp service
127.0.0.1:smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o myorigin=$myhostname
  -o cleanup_service_name=cleanup_local
  -o inet_interfaces=loopback-only
  -o local_header_rewrite_clients=permit_inet_interfaces

# edit pickup sevice with this two options
pickup    unix  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
  -o myorigin=$myhostname
  -o cleanup_service_name=cleanup_local

# add this for local email cleanup
cleanup_local   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
  -o myorigin=$myhostname
  -o rewrite_service_name=rewrite_local

# add this for local email basic rewrite
rewrite_local   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
  -o myorigin=$myhostname
  -o local_header_rewrite_clients=permit_inet_interfaces

# Then for each public IP assigned to the machine, add smtp service like this
192.168.3.85:smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
# and remove default service smtp inet [..cut..] smtpd
```